# Proper JSON notation syntax in a Dockerfile when piping output through multiple commands on a `CMD` line?

Tags: docker

I am running through a Docker tutorial, and the Dockerfile contains the following line:

`CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay`

When using `hadolint` to lint the file, I get this recommendation:

`DL3025 Use arguments JSON notation for CMD and ENTRYPOINT arguments`

So I update the `CMD` line with JSON notation for the arguments:

`CMD ["/usr/games/fortune", "-a", "|", "cowsay"]`

Now, after I (re)build the image and run it, I get this error:

`(null)/|: No such file or directory`

What is the correct way to use proper JSON notation syntax when I need to pipe output from one command to another on a `CMD` line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is a shell symbol which only works within a shell environment.

```
CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

This will work as follows: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "command param1 param2"]`.

```
CMD ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
```

This will not invoke a shell, so `|` will not function.

You may reference something from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

For your situation, you need to use a shell to leverage `|` so the correct way could be something like this:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "/usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay"]
```