# How to give JSON notation syntax for given command in dockerfile for linting purpose?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, lint, hadolint

Could you please provide JSON notation syntax for following command for Dockerfile Linting?

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Proper JSON notation syntax in a Dockerfile when piping output through multiple commands on a `CMD` line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920860/proper-json-notation-syntax-in-a-dockerfile-when-piping-output-through-multiple) you need to provide the command as such

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app"]
```

Comment: How can we provide JSON notation for "--workers 1 --threads 8 app:app"?

Comment: I edited my answer. Did not copy all the command